# Подскажите в переборе массива php

Tags: php, foreach, for

Как перебрать массив следующего типа?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [code] => 453157
            [name] => Круг полировальный черный на липучке 125мм финишный
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [code] => 454772
            [name] => Адаптер для полировального круга липучка 125мм с переходником для дрели
        )
)
```

И значения вывести в таблицу

```
453157   Круг полировальный черный на липучке 125мм финишный
454772   Адаптер для полировального круга липучка 125мм с переходником для дрели
```

Comment: Где ваш код? Попытки? В чем сам вопрос?

Comment: Как foreach перебрать массив и вывести виде таблицы

Comment: Посмотреть в __миллионах__ мануалов как написать `foreach` и перебрать.

Comment: Смотрел, и если бы нашел ответ то тут бы его не задавал
Именно такой массив не могу перебрать

Comment: Ну код хотя б покажите, есть у вас код-то?

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример как сделать перебор значений с использованием `foreach`

```
<?php

$array = [
    [
        'code' => 453157, 
        'name' => 'Круг полировальный черный на липучке 125мм финишный'
    ],
    [
        'code' => 454772, 
        'name' => 'Адаптер для полировального круга липучка 125мм с переходником для дрели'
    ]
];

$old_syntax = array(
    array(
        'code' => 453157,
        'name' => 'Круг полировальный черный на липучке 125мм финишный',
    ),
    array(
        'code' => 454772,
        'name' => 'Адаптер для полировального круга липучка 125мм с переходником для дрели',
    ),
);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>Использование FOREACH для перебора значений</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Код</td>
                <td>Название</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php if (count($old_syntax) > 0): ?>
                <?php foreach ($old_syntax as $row): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?= $row['code'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $row['name'] ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">Нет данных для вывода</td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не мешайте `HTML` в `PHP`, получается каша которую очень трудно поддерживать и читать в общем. В лучшем случае используйте *шаблонизатор* (**TWIG**, etc).

Answer (score -1):

```
$arr = [
    [
        'code' => 453157, 
        'name' => 'Круг полировальный черный на липучке 125мм финишный'
    ],
    [
        'code' => 454772, 
        'name' => ' Адаптер для полировального круга липучка 125мм с переходником для дрели'
    ]
];

echo '<table border=1>';
foreach ($arr as $k) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($k as $i) {
        echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>';
    }   
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD по комменту - все работает - вы какую версию php пользуете? Я всегда пробую предлагаемый код - это php 7.3

А так - измените оформление массивов :

```
// Начиная с PHP 5.4
$array = [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];
```

Comment: Так не работает

Comment: У меня массив другого плана [0] => Array и [1] => Array

Comment: @Алексей Марченко - добавил в ответ

Comment: А что не работает-то, вы можете пояснить или нам надо угадывать?